# Python regex findall with all specific substrings

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to get the output of the following matching regex as

all the Sectors for eg. ['Sector-34, Noida', 'Sec 434 Gurgaon', 'sec100']

P.S - sec47, \n gurgaon is the special case

But I suspect the output is quite weird as [('', 'tor')]

```
import re

string = "Sector-34, Noida is found to be awesome place I went to eat burgers there and Sec 434 Gurgoan is also good sec100 is one the finest places for outing."

match =  re.findall(r"Sec(tor)?-?\d+\s+?\w+|Sec(tor)?\s+?\d+", string, re.IGNORECASE)

print match
```

Thanks, in Advance!

Comment: Are you sure you need `sec100` and not `sec100 is`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew. Thanks for replying! Yes I want sec100 too

Comment: I mean, how do you know when to match word chars after digits, and when not? What is the rule difference between `Sec 434 Gurgaon` and `sec100`? The absence of space? To see what I mean - [`Sec(?:tor)?-?\s*\d+\W+?\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/bM8eP4/2).

Comment: Ok, try [`Sec(?:tor)?(?:\d+|-?\s*\d+\W+\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/sE6uT0/3) - see https://ideone.com/rZ4YXv

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yaa. I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way that will give the expected output, but is not a general way (because you didn't provide us with general conditions):

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?:[sS]ec(?:tor)?(?:-|\s+)?\d+\W?\s+[A-Z][a-z]+)|[sS]ec(?:tor)?\d+', string)
['Sector-34, Noida', 'Sec 434 Gurgoan', 'sec100']
```

Notes:

1. Here I used `\W` (none word characters) in order to match the characters like `,` in first match. If you think other none-word characters are wring you should change that to `,`.
2. We have 2 option here:

   1. `(?:[sS]ec(?:tor)?(?:-|\s+)?\d+\W?\s+[A-Z][a-z]+)`
   2. `[sS]ec(?:tor)?\d+`

As you can see for the second part I didn't consider a word after sector and the digit, if you think that there might be a word after that you can add `(?:\s+[A-Z][a-z]+)?` after that.

Comment: Having two alternatives in a group that can match at the same position in the string is not best practice.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You mean `(?:\s+[A-Z][a-z]+)?` or what?

Comment: I mean the two alternatives start with the same pattern. See my answer for a way to contract that - just make sure the common part is *outside* the alternation group.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew As I described in my answer, the reason that I've separate them is because there are another words with different conditions. for example fro the second option maybe we had word after that  like `sec100 Noida`.

Comment: Strange, I have just checked, and your solution does extract `sec100 is` - https://ideone.com/iYIrUG

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Mmmm, yeah it's wired. What's the version of its python interpreter?

Comment: You mean at IDEONE? I used Python 2.x.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ohum, I tested it in my terminal for 2.7 and 3.4 and it works well, by only matching the `sec100`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Aha, I got it, you shouldn't use `ignorecase` flag. That's why I used a capitalized character word at the leading of the words.

Comment: Did anyone notice that OPs requirement has changed ;)  And none of our answers satisfy the current requirement. :D

Comment: I'm sorry I changed the OP wanted to include that case too btw I fixed it later case myself . and I will revert previous OP. 
Thanks, guys for all your help

Answer (score 0):

You could go for:

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r'(\b[Ss]ec(?:tor)?[- ]?\d+\b[,\s]*\b\w+\b)')

string = """
Sector-34, Noida is found to be awesome place I went to eat burgers there and Sec 434 Gurgoan is also good sec47, 
gurgaon is one the finest places for outing.
"""

sectors = [match.group(1).replace("\n", "") \
            for match in rx.finditer(string)]
print(sectors)
# ['Sector-34, Noida', 'Sec 434 Gurgoan', 'sec47, gurgaon']
```

Otherwise, please provide additional information / sectors.